# Is there a bimonad on the category of sets that is exact?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

I am wondering if it is possible to have a bimonad on $\mathsf{Set}$ that preserves equalizers on both sides?  What about a bimonad that is exact?  Can you give an example?

Let me try to explain what I mean by  preserving equalizers on both  sides.  One of the reasons I am interested in Bimonads, is that I think they  may be internal categories in an endofunctor category on Set.  Have a look at [this post](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad).

I want to interpret the monoidal product $\otimes$ as functor composition.  In the link, they require that the monoidal product preserve equalizers on both sides.  This means that we want the functor composition to preserve equalizers.  I am not actually sure what it would mean for the functor composition to preserve equalizers.

A bimonad is a monad that is a comonad, and these interact according to a mixed distributive law, as described by Mesablishvili and Wisbauer [here](http://www.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~wisbauer/Hopfmonad.pdf).

Comment: What do you mean by on both sides?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Based on past questions, I think Ben means that both $M \circ -$ and $- \circ M$ preserve equalizers (but of course the latter is automatic since equalizers are computed pointwise). Also, I'll bet that reflexive equalizers would be enough for his purposes.

Comment: @ToddTrimble what is the Monad you are describing?  I have a question [here about something similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506020/what-is-this-monad-comonad).  Is it the same?

Comment: I wasn't describing any monad in particular; I was just interpreting for მამუკაჯიბლაძე what I thought you meant by "preserves equalizers on both sides".

Comment: Let me write what I mean in the question.